# Solvable extension is solvable by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, solvable-groups

I have trouble understanding Serge Lang's proof that a solvable extension is solvable by radicals. More precisely, I cannot figure out why did he pick such a number.

> *Proof.* Assume that $E/k$ is solvable, and let $K$ be a finite solvable Galois extension of $k$ containing $E$. Let $m$ be the product of all primes unequal to the characteristic dividing the degree $[K:k]$, and let $F=k(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity. Then $F/k$ is abelian. We lift $K$ over $F$. Then $KF$ is solvable over $F$. There is a tower of subfields between $F$ and $KF$ such that each step is cyclic of prime order, because every solvable group admits a tower of subgroups of the same type, and we can use theorem 1.10. By theorem 6.2 and theorem 6.4, we conclude that $KF$ is solvable by radicals over $F$, and hence is solvable by radicals over $k$. This proves that $E/k$ is solvable by radicals.

I understand that $F/k$ is solvable by radical by definition. However, why did he even define $F$, or more precisely, $m$ in such a manner? Avoiding the characteristic of $k$ makes sense, and taking $m$ to be a factor of $[K:k]$ also makes sense, but why does it have to be the radical of $[K:k]$ (divided by $p$ when $p|[K:k]$)? For example if $[K:k]=24$ and the charactersitic is $0$, why would we pick $m=2 \times 3$ instead of $4$ or $12$ or $8$? Does it have anything to do with $KF/F$?

---

Here are theorems mentioned in Lang's proof.

> **Theorem 1.10.** Let $K$ be a Galois extension of $k$ with group $G$. Let $F$ be a subfield, $k \subset F \subset K$, and let $H=G(K/F)$. Then $F$ is normal over $k$ if and only if $H$ is normal in $G$. If $F$ is normal over $k$, then the restriction map $\sigma \mapsto \sigma|_F$ is a homomorphism of $G$ onto the Galois group of $F$ over $k$, whose kernel is $H$. We thus have $G(F/k) \cong G/H$.

> **Theorem 6.2.** Let $k$ be a field, $n$ an integer $>0$ prime to the characteristic of $k$, and assume that there is a primitive $n$-th root of unity in $k$.
>
> (i) Let $K$ be a cyclic extension of degree $n$. Then there exists $\alpha \in K$ such that $K=k(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ satisfies an equation $X^n-a=0$ for some $a \in k$.
>
> (ii) Conversely, let $a \in k$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $X^n-a$. Then $k(\alpha)$ is cyclic over $k$, of degree $d$, $d|n$, and $\alpha^d$ is an element of $k$.

> **Theorem 6.4.** Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$.
>
> (i) Let $K$ be a cyclic extension of $k$ of degree $p$. Then there exists $\alpha \in K$ such that $K=k(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ satisfies an equation $X^p-X-a=0$ with some $a \in k$.
>
> (ii) Conersely, given $a \in k$, the polynomial $f(X)=X^p-X-a$ either has one root in $k$, in which case all its roots are in $k$< or it is irreducible. In this latter case, if $\alpha$ is a root then $k(\alpha)$ is cyclic of degree $p$ over $k$.

Comment: To conclude that the cyclic extension of order $p$ (with $p$ different from the characteristic) is given by radicals (that is, to apply Theorem 6.2 when $p$ is not the charact) you need your base field to contain a primitive $p$^th root of unity. For the extension of degree $m$, this can happen for any prime $p$ that divides $m$ and does not divide the characteristic. So $F$ is defined to ensure that it has a primitive $p$th root of unity for every $p$ that may occur as a degree of a prime-order subextension and is not the characteristic. This value is enough

Comment: If $[K:k]=24$, then when you decompose into extensions of prime order you may run into an extension of order $3$. To conclude this extension is given by radicals, you need your base field to contain a primitive cubic root of unity. Adding a $4$th root of unity doesn't suffice (though adding a $12$th, would, since the $4$th power of a primitive $12$th root of unity will be a primitive $3$rd root of unity. The definition is the smallest number that guarantees you always have all the required primitive roots of unity.

Comment: Hey, maybe I'm just not informed about this, but why leave this as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I can see now this $m$ can make sure we will not run out of roots of unity for cyclic extensions of degree $p|[K:k]$. But have we run out of prime numbers in $[KF:F]$? I can't see an explicit relation between $[KF:F]$ and $[K:k]$ yet.

Comment: Let's use the example $[K:k]=24$ again. Now $F$ is of degree $2$. But inside the extension $KF/F$, can we be certain that we will only be looking for cyclic subextensions of degree $2$ or $3$, instead of $5,7,11$?

Comment: Use the second part of Theorem 6.2. If you have a tower $k=K_0\leq K_1\leq\cdots\leq K_n=K$, with the subextensions $K_{i+1}/K_i$ of prime degree that is not the characteristic given by a single element $\alpha_i$ that is a root of $X^p-a$. Your tower between $F$ and $KF$ is $F=K_0F\leq K_1F\leq K_nF=KF$, the corresponding extension $K_{i+1}F/K_iF$ is given by the element $\alpha_i$ which satisfies $X^p-a$, and therefore is of degree **dividing** $p$, hence is either $1$ or $p$. You cannot introduce any new primes in the process.

Comment: Ok; this got lengthier than I expected. I'll post an answer with it all later.